# Back button of the browser and iframe comaptiblity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using iframe to display the content on a page. I have links on the page which help me traverse back and forth as required. How can I use the back button of the browser to do the same as the url does not change only the content in the iframe changes?

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history) to replicate your navigation. For your iframe, you'll have to use `iframe.contentWindow.history` to access window's history object